# MariaDB, tomcat connection pool access denied Error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, mariadb

### First of all, I am sorry, I am not good at English.

### Hi! I have some problems about connecting mariaDB from Java web project using tomcat connection pool and JNDI.

Here are Exception logs from eclipse console.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:605)
...(etc)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:238)
...(etc)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
...(etc)
```

and I set connection pool information into Tomcat server context.xml file like this

```
<Resource 
        name = "jdbc/maria" 
        auth = "Container"
        type = "javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pcj01142"
        username = "root"
        password = "mypassword"
        maxActive="50" 
        maxWait = "-1"/>
```

and There are some facts that

1. I can connect mariadb through client console, and HeidiSQL using id 'root' and password 'mypassword'.
2. Default combination of mariadb server is 'utf8_general_ci'
3. There is a database in mariadb server which is named 'pcj01142'

Here are some attempts I have tried to fix my problem but doesn't work

- Reinstalling mariadb and apache tomcat9
- Resetting root user password
- Adding new user which have all privileges
- Stoping DB server and restarting

I also tried to start tomcat itself not through the eclipse but, result was same.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

## I solved this problem myself.

The problem was collision between MySQL and MariaDB using same port number(3306).

When I stoped MySQL, problem wad solved.